# Classpath Git and eGit installed, possible they're different instances and conflicting?

Tags: eclipse, git

I have eGit running in Eclipse and Git installed (on Windows, installed by the installer, I don't see it on my path or in system variables when I issue 'set').

When I create something in Eclipse and add it to the Git *Index* I see different results to when I run `git status` **via Git-Bash**. More puzzling though is that I see the same file twice when I issue *status*.

**E.g.**

```
padewan@LT03253 /c/work/workspace/project root (master)
$ git status`
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   some-nested-module/src/main/java/packageName/Foo.java

Changes not staged for commit:
 (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
 (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   some-nested-module/src/main/java/packageName/Foo.java
```

**Notice that that same file shows up as staged (green) in the status, and `not staged` (red).**

In all cases I add things to the *index* via Eclipse (not working on command line except for feedback about status' of commitable files).

Comment: From VonC Comment below: "you can see more about that index/working tree: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notice that that same file shows up as staged (green) in the status, and not staged (red).

That only means your file has been added to the index, and has since been modified locally (the new modifications are not part of the index).

The `git-bash status` simply provide a unified vision of the status.

See more at "[Git Basics - Recording Changes to the Repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository)":

[image: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/book/02-git-basics/images/lifecycle.png]

You can modify a file, even *after* it has been staged.

Comment: So it means that it should show up in staged and modified? I would have thought the added file and the modifications all all revealed in one result - that is, staged.

Comment: @DocBird no, you can add gradullay changes to a file to the index. That allows you to experiment, while being ready to commit what you want (ie what you already staged)

Comment: @DocBird you can see more about that index/working tree: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository